# It seems I deployed my angular app in github pages, but still getting 404 page while trying to access

Tags: github, github-pages

[image]

[image]

My Github Repo :https://github.com/Praveen111/Cards-Project

Not sure why I'm getting 404 page. Please guide me if I'm missing anything.

Comment: `Hint: are you sure that you have setup the directory correctly?` - looks like that library hasn't been updated to account for the fact that the default output directory for an Angular CLI project is now `dist/<project-name>/`, not just `dist/`. https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/issues/37

Comment: It has worked post I checked Angular official documentation, anyways thanks